# How to zoom in Windows using the mouse? (like in OS X)

Tags: windows, zoom, magnifier

In OS X, you just assign <kbd>Cmd</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + mouse scroll for zooming in. This works anywhere, in any app.

Windows 7 also has a nice magnifier, and has some hotkeys:

> #### Magnifier keyboard shortcuts
>
> The following table contains keyboard shortcuts for working with
>   Magnifier.
>
> ```
> Windows logo key + Plus Sign or Minus Sign    Zoom in or out
> Ctrl+Alt+Spacebar Preview the desktop in full-screen mode
> Ctrl+Alt+F    Switch to full-screen mode
> Ctrl+Alt+L    Switch to lens mode
> Ctrl+Alt+D    Switch to docked mode
> Ctrl+Alt+I    Invert colors
> Ctrl+Alt+arrow keys   Pan in the direction of the arrow keys
> Ctrl+Alt+R    Resize the lens
> Windows logo key + Esc    Exit Magnifier
> ```

... but I want to use the mouse for zooming in and out like in OS X. Is that possible?

Comment: You cannot use ctrl+scroll for zooming because it's already assigned to desktop/explorer icon zooming

Answer (score 9):

Try [ZoomIt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897434.aspx) for the zooming (free from SysInternals). I prefer ZoomIt more than Windows Magnifier. It even allows me to draw on the screen -- perfect for presentations. The thing is, you'll still have to use the keyboard to activate ZoomIt; zooming in and out can be done using the mouse wheel.

The only way to get exactly -- at least based on my knowledge -- what you want is to use AutoHotKey script that traps the Ctrl+Wheel events and emulate WinKey+Plus Sign or WinKey+Minus Sign key press.

Answer (score 7):

[AeroZoom](https://wandersick.blogspot.com/p/aerozoom-for-windows-7-magnifier.html) does exactly what you want.

It uses the Windows Magnifier as a back-end, but allows you to set up <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or some other key in combination with the scroll wheel to zoom in and zoom out.

It also has many other settings not accessible from the Magnifier, like hiding the magnifying lens from the screen.

Comment: Based on the demo view I wouldn't say exactly. That doesn't seem like OS X zoom. The zoom in OS X is hardware accelerated, smooth and precise. This instead seems very imprecise and stuttering. On OS X, scrolling doesn't increment set zoom levels, it is similar to smooth pinch and zoom on mobile phones.

Comment: While this isn't as smooths as on Mac, it fill the void when using a Windows PC and wanting to see a closeup, Mac style, because your home computer is a Mac.

Comment: Thanks, this is 100% exactly what I was looking for after switching from Mac to Windows.

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking for exactly this forever. This should be bought by MS and made part of the OS. You've saved a blind man much trouble, thank you again.

Answer (score -2):

1. Press **Windows Key** + **"+"** key to activate. The [Magnifier Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdmmO.png) appears.
2. In the magnifier window that appears, click on the gear icon to select the settings.
3. Sroll down in the settings till you find the ["Have Magnifier follow:"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u6wi.png) settings. Here uncheck all the settings except for "Mouse cursor" as shown in the attached image.
4. Close the settings.

Now, when ever you want to zoom in, move the mouse to the center of your zoom and press the **Windows Key** + **"+"** key combination to zoom in and the **Windows Key** + **"-"** key combination to zoom out. Having the other settings checked makes the magnifier jump about unpredictably.

Comment: (1) What version(s) of Windows support this?  (2) Can you provide a reference? … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: This is not zooming with the mouse at all, this is zooming with the keyboard.